# Find the sequences of numbers in the list?

Tags: java

there is a task to find all the sequences of numbers in the list, then add them another list. For example, there is such a sequence of numbers in list

> 12222533343332

Only numbers must appear in the resulting list like this `44` `77` `88` `000` A prerequisite is that repeated numbers must stand side by side 
For example, so

> **5**12222**5**33343332**5**

5 should not fall into the resulting list because they are not near each other, respectively (not a sequence)

```
List<Integer> topList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int count = 0;
    boolean flag = true;

    while (count < topList.size()){
        while (flag) {
            for (int j = count + 1; j < topList.size(); j++) {
                if (topList.get(count).equals(topList.get(j))) {
                    result.add(topList.get(j));
                    System.out.println(result);
                    flag = false;
                }else {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
```

I try to compare the elements in pairs and add them to the sheet, but it is added to a couple of more elements for example instead of `22222`, I get `222222`. And instead of `333` and one more sequence `333`. I get `333` and `33`. How can I improve?

Comment: `StreamEx.of(list).groupRuns(Object::equals).filter(list -> list.size() > 1).flatMap(List::stream).toList()`

Comment: @Metisto_Fell see answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is to store the index `j` of the beginning of each sequence. Then, when a sequence is broken at index `i`, if `i-j > 1`, output `i-j` instances of the number at `j`

```
static List<Integer> extractRepeats(List<Integer> in)
{
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1, j=0; i<=in.size(); i++)
    {
        if((i == in.size() || in.get(i) != in.get(i-1)) && ++j < i)
        {
            for(j--; j<i; j++) 
            {
                result.add(in.get(j));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String s = "12222533343332";
    List<Integer> in = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String ns : s.split("")) in.add(Integer.parseInt(ns));
    System.out.println(extractRepeats(in));     
}
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: it is taking `O(n^2)` while you can do in `O(n)`

Answer (score 2):

Easily visible problem was that `topList.get(count).equals(topList.get(j))` in this condition you are checking not only contiguous numbers but also others too.

the second problem is the `flag` is set `false` after checking for only one number (one inner loop), there is not way to enter the second loop again, so since `count` is still less than `toList.size()` and there is no way to increment it, the outer loop will enter infinite loop.

You may want to try the following instead;

**EDIT**

It works like this, it tries to find  equal adjacent pair of numbers and add one of them to the list and continues doing the same until it finds non-equal pair(one needed to be add, other not), this result will miss to add one last equal number to the list, so to include this to the list we need check `repeat` and add it. done.

**it takes `O(n)`**

```
    List<Integer> topList = new ArrayList<>();
    topList.addAll(Arrays.asList(5,1,2,2,2,2,5,3,3,3,4,3,3,3,2,5));
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();       
    boolean repeat = false;
    for ( int i=0 ; i < topList.size() - 1; ){
      if((topList.get(i++) - topList.get(i)) == 0 ){    
        repeat = true;      
        result.add(topList.get(i-1));
        continue;           
      }
      if(repeat){
        result.add(topList.get(i-1));
        repeat=false;
      } 
    }
   if(repeat)
       result.add(topList.get(topList.size() - 1));
  System.out.println(result);
```

**output**

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,3]
```

Comment: You need to handle the case of a sequence at the end of the input, e.g. `[1,1,2,2]`. Currently your code outputs `[1,1,2]`. In this case `repeat` is true at the end of the `for` loop, and you need to add the last element of `topList` to `result`.

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution for this problems is done with `regex` :

```
String s = "12222533343332";
String pattern = "(.)\\1+";  // find more than one of the same characters

// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

// Now create matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher(s);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Comment: Yes it works, but what if you can not use a string? You only have a list that you can not impose on a string)